# md-table in Angular Material 2

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular-cdk

I am working with [Angular Material Table.](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview) In Html code, there is

```html
<ng-container cdkColumnDef="userId">
  <md-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef> ID </md-header-cell>
  <md-cell *cdkCellDef="let row"> {{row.id}} </md-cell>
</ng-container>
```

I found out that cdkHeaderCellDef and cdkCellDef are from [CDK Table](https://material.angular.io/guide/cdk-table)

I am getting error saying "**Can't bind to 'cdkHeaderRowDef' since it isn't a known property of 'md-header-row'.**"

How can I solve this ?

Comment: Be sure to add `MdTableModule` in your `imports` (`NgModule`).

Comment: @developer033 Yes, I added before itself

Comment: can you provide whole html for table definition?

Comment: @DavidGabrichidze I just copy paste the whole html,ts and css from angular material table.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `cdkHeaderCellDef` and `cdkCellDef` are part of the `@angular/cdk` library and exported in the `CdkTableModule`.

Include this module in your app's imports

Comment: Awesome, Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
 import { CdkTableModule } from '@angular/cdk';
```

add this to the top of your component and to the top of app.module.ts 
and then on app.module.ts add CdkTableModule to imports as given below.

```
@NgModule({
   declarations: [

],
imports: [
    CdkTableModule

],
providers: [

],
bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
```

there may be declarations and providers but in the above snippet they are ignored for convenience.

Comment: Needs to be 
import { CdkTableModule } from '@angular/cdk/table';