# Angular material 2 data table Error Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:

Tags: angular-material2

The md-table provides a Material Design styled data-table that can be used to display rows of data.

This table builds on the foundation of the CDK data-table and uses a similar interface for its data source input and template, except that its element selectors will be prefixed with md- instead of cdk-

### I have this error Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:

#### This is my products.component.html

```
          <md-card class="chart-container">
            <div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
              <md-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">

                <!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
                The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition" -->

                <!-- ID Column -->
                <ng-container cdkColumnDef="userId">
                  <md-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef> ID </md-header-cell>
                  <md-cell *cdkCellDef="let row"> {{row.id}} </md-cell>
                </ng-container>

                <!-- Progress Column -->
                <ng-container cdkColumnDef="progress">
                  <md-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef> Progress </md-header-cell>
                  <md-cell *cdkCellDef="let row"> {{row.progress}}% </md-cell>
                </ng-container>

                <!-- Name Column -->
                <ng-container cdkColumnDef="userName">
                  <md-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef> Name </md-header-cell>
                  <md-cell *cdkCellDef="let row"> {{row.name}} </md-cell>
                </ng-container>

                <!-- Color Column -->
                <ng-container cdkColumnDef="color">
                  <md-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef>Color</md-header-cell>  
                  <md-cell *cdkCellDef="let row" [style.color]="row.color"> {{row.color}} </md-cell>
                </ng-container>

                <md-header-row *cdkHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></md-header-row> <----- Heare is the problem
                <md-row *cdkRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></md-row>  <----- Heare is the problem
              </md-table>
            </div>
          </md-card>



Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'cdkHeaderRowDef' since it isn't a known property of 'md-header-row'.
1. If 'md-header-row' is an Angular component and it has 'cdkHeaderRowDef' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'md-header-row' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
                </ng-container>

                <md-header-row [ERROR ->]*cdkHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></md-header-row>
                <md-row *cdkRowDef="let row; col"): ng:///AppModule/AdminProductsComponent.html@60:31
Property binding cdkHeaderRowDef not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations". ("
                </ng-container>

                [ERROR ->]<md-header-row *cdkHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></md-header-row>
                <md-row *cdkRowDe"): ng:///AppModule/AdminProductsComponent.html@60:16
Can't bind to 'cdkRowDefColumns' since it isn't a known property of 'md-row'.
1. If 'md-row' is an Angular component and it has 'cdkRowDefColumns' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'md-row' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("        <md-header-row *cdkHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></md-header-row>
                <md-row [ERROR ->]*cdkRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></md-row>
              </md-table>
            </di"): ng:///AppModule/AdminProductsComponent.html@61:24
Property binding cdkRowDefColumns not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations". ("                <md-header-row *cdkHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></md-header-row>
                [ERROR ->]<md-row *cdkRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></md-row>
              </md-table>
        "): ng:///AppModule/AdminProductsComponent.html@61:16
    at syntaxError (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:86242:34)
    at TemplateParser.parse (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:97363:19)
    at JitCompiler._compileTemplate (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:111515:39)
    at http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:111435:62
    at Set.forEach (native)
    at JitCompiler._compileComponents (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:111435:19)
    at http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:111322:19
    at Object.then (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:86231:148)
    at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:111321:26)
    at JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:111250:37)
```

### This is the products.componetn.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {DataSource} from '@angular/cdk';
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/startWith';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/merge';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin-products',
  templateUrl: './admin-products.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin-products.component.css']
})
export class AdminProductsComponent implements OnInit {

  curentPage: string;
  isDarkTheme: any;
  totalProducts: any = 88;
  totalNeeds: any = 88;
  totalBrands: any = 88;
  totalAgeGroups: any = 88;

  constructor() {
    this.curentPage = 'Products';
    this.isDarkTheme = false;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}


/** Constants used to fill up our data base. */
const COLORS = ['maroon', 'red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'olive', 'green', 'purple',
  'fuchsia', 'lime', 'teal', 'aqua', 'blue', 'navy', 'black', 'gray'];
const NAMES = ['Maia', 'Asher', 'Olivia', 'Atticus', 'Amelia', 'Jack',
  'Charlotte', 'Theodore', 'Isla', 'Oliver', 'Isabella', 'Jasper',
  'Cora', 'Levi', 'Violet', 'Arthur', 'Mia', 'Thomas', 'Elizabeth'];


export interface UserData {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  progress: string;
  color: string;
}


/** An example database that the data source uses to retrieve data for the table. */
export class ExampleDatabase {
  /** Stream that emits whenever the data has been modified. */
  dataChange: BehaviorSubject<UserData[]> = new BehaviorSubject<UserData[]>([]);
  get data(): UserData[] { return this.dataChange.value; }

  constructor() {
    // Fill up the database with 100 users.
    for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) { this.addUser(); }
  }

  /** Adds a new user to the database. */
  addUser() {
    const copiedData = this.data.slice();
    copiedData.push(this.createNewUser());
    this.dataChange.next(copiedData);
  }

  /** Builds and returns a new User. */
  private createNewUser() {
    const name =
        NAMES[Math.round(Math.random() * (NAMES.length - 1))] + ' ' +
        NAMES[Math.round(Math.random() * (NAMES.length - 1))].charAt(0) + '.';

    return {
      id: (this.data.length + 1).toString(),
      name: name,
      progress: Math.round(Math.random() * 100).toString(),
      color: COLORS[Math.round(Math.random() * (COLORS.length - 1))]
    };
  }
}

/**
 * Data source to provide what data should be rendered in the table. Note that the data source
 * can retrieve its data in any way. In this case, the data source is provided a reference
 * to a common data base, ExampleDatabase. It is not the data source's responsibility to manage
 * the underlying data. Instead, it only needs to take the data and send the table exactly what
 * should be rendered.
 */
export class ExampleDataSource extends DataSource<any> {
  constructor(private _exampleDatabase: ExampleDatabase) {
    super();
  }

  /** Connect function called by the table to retrieve one stream containing the data to render. */
  connect(): Observable<UserData[]> {
    return this._exampleDatabase.dataChange;
  }

  disconnect() {}
}
```

Comment: can you post your error?

Comment: did you import `MdTableModule`  and `CdkTableModule` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [md-table in Angular Material 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44997756/md-table-in-angular-material-2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

import **CdkTableModule** in your app.module.ts file

```
import { CdkTableModule } from '@angular/cdk';
```

and add CdkTableModule to the imports

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    CdkTableModule,
    MaterialModule
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Answered here: [md-table in Angular Material 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44997756/md-table-in-angular-material-2/44998147#44998147)

---

The `cdkHeaderCellDef` and `cdkCellDef` are part of the `@angular/cdk` library and exported in the `CdkTableModule`.

Include this module in your app's imports

Comment: Please flag duplicates instead of double dipping fake internet points.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, didn't realize that was a thing (just joined StackOverflow)

Comment: No worries, your response speaks highly of you.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I'm starting at angular, and I had a similar error, using version **2.0.0-beta.12** of angular material, the documentation of your page (material.angular.io/components/table/examples ) uses the prefix **"md"**, which was removed in this new version(now **mat**), here you can see the notes of said change

https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#deprecation-of-md-prefix

It may be useful for someone to use this information if they are new, since I followed the examples and did everything that indicates the answer to this question and the example did not work until I change to this example:

github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/material-examples/table-basic/table-basic-example.html

Greetings.